# SQL running total up to X

Tags: t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2019. I have a table with invoices that has 5 rows in it.

```
+---------+---------+
| invoice |  amount |
+---------+---------+
| ABC     |     100 |
| DEF     |     125 |
| GHI     |     150 |
| JKL     |     160 |
| MNO     |     170 |
```

I want to return each row that it takes to get a running total of up to 235, and the partial of it. Invoice GHI contains the remaining partial amount of 10 (235 - 100 - 125).

```
+---------+---------+
| invoice |  amount |
+---------+---------+
| ABC     |     100 |
| DEF     |     125 |
| GHI     |      10 |
+---------+---------+
```

Since those are the only 3 lines to get it to the requested 235.
I am thinking of something like a user defined function that returns a table, but i can't seem to come up with anything that will handle the running total with the partial on the last one.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve. Find 3 rows that sum up to a given number?

Comment: Correct. I want a returning SQL that returns the 3 lines needed to get to the 235, and then amount "used" on each line, hence the 100,125,and 10.

Comment: Could you please share your table structure so I could write an answer?

Comment: invoice char(10), amount decimal(10,2), that has the 5 invoices in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the reason behind the summing the invoices remain unclear to me from your post, however here is my solution.

First, lets create a sample table with the 5 invoice lines.

```
create table dbo.invoices
(
    invoice char(10),
    amount decimal(10,2)
);

insert into dbo.invoices
values ('ABC', 100), ('DEF', 125), ('GHI', 150), ('JKL', 160), ('MNO', 170);
```

Using windowing functions we can check if we have achieved the target amount:

```
declare @target_amount decimal(10,2) = 235;

with input as (
select invoice
, amount
, running_total = sum(amount) over(order by invoice asc)
, target_amount = @target_amount
from dbo.invoices
), net_amount as (
select *
, net_amount = target_amount - running_total
from input
), selection as (
select *
, new_amount = case when net_amount > 0 then amount else amount + net_amount end
, invoice_filter = case when lag(net_amount) over( order by invoice) < 0 then 0 else 1 end
from net_amount
) -- end result
select invoice
, original_amount = amount
, new_amount
from selection
where invoice_filter = 1
```

And the result looks like this:

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+
| invoice | original_amount | new_amount |
+---------+-----------------+------------+
| ABC     |          100.00 |     100.00 |
| DEF     |          125.00 |     125.00 |
| GHI     |          150.00 |      10.00 |
+---------+-----------------+------------+
```

Comment: AWESOME!!!! Thank you so much. I will have to study this to completely understand everything that you did. Very elegant!!